# How to mount drive at Google Cloud (Google Compute Engine)?

Tags: linux, centos, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have runned instance in Google Compute Engine with 120Gb boot drive.

But I'm not able to use it.

```
1. sudo df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       9.9G  1.1G  8.3G  12% /
tmpfs           3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev/shm

2. sudo ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Nov  3 09:00 /dev/disk/by-id/google-instance-3 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  3 09:00 /dev/disk/by-id/google-instance-3-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Nov  3 09:00 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_instance-3 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov  3 09:00 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_instance-3-part1 -> ../../sda1

3. sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 134.2 GB, 134217728000 bytes
4 heads, 32 sectors/track, 2048000 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 128 * 512 = 65536 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003b4b9
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              17      163825    10483712+  83  Linux
```

I have spended several hours trying to mount it in different ways even have changed instance but unsuccessfully.

UPD: If someone has this issue follow this instruction: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#repartitionrootpd

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24102667/3618671) for how to automate the resize process for your VM's boot disks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you issue the mount command, check if you are not mounting a whole drive instead of a single partition or try to add the correct partition to the mount command.

(ex.: mount /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_instance-3-part1 /your/mount/location )

Did you had any error messages?

Have you also tried [gsutil - Google Cloud Storage Tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil)?

Comment: 1.  mount /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_instance-3-part1 /mnt/new - no error messages at all. but no result. If I change to Google_PersistentDisk_instance-3 mount: /dev/sda already mounted or /mnt/new2 busy

Comment: @inno.vlad what about error messages? What does `dmesg | tail` shows you right after you try to mount the drive?

Comment: eth0: no IPv6 routers present
udev: starting version 147
SELinux:  2048 avtab hash slots, 294585 rules.
SELinux:  9 users, 12 roles, 4142 types, 228 bools, 1 sens, 1024 cats
SELinux:  81 classes, 294585 rules
type=1305 audit(1415009600.895:260): audit_pid=0 old=885 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 r
es=1
type=1305 audit(1415009600.993:261): audit_enabled=0 old=1 auid=0 ses=1 subj=system_u:system_r:auditctl_t:s0 res=1
type=1305 audit(1415009601.015:262): audit_pid=4036 old=0 auid=0 ses=1 subj=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=1

Comment: /dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,barrier=0)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/new type ext4 (rw)

Comment: its strange answer: mount: /dev/sda already mounted or /mnt/new2 busy because it was new folder and if sda has mounted where is i? (Disk /dev/sda: 134.2 GB, 134217728000 bytes)

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       9.9G  1.4G  8.0G  15% /
tmpfs           3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       9.9G  1.4G  8.0G  15% /mnt/new

Comment: no. umount: /mnt/new2: not mounted

Comment: You have a drive with 134.2GB but you only have one partition with 10GB created. If you want to use more space from that drive, you will have to either re-create sda1 with more blocks, or add new partitions to the disk.

Comment: No problem. Glad it works.